# scipy.loadmat() doesnt accept relative path

Tags: python, scipy, mat

I tried to give a relative path to scipy.loadmat() but it looks like its not accepting relative path(only accepts system path).
I did a workaround for this :

```
 cwd = os.getcwd()
model_path = os.path.join(cwd, 'Models.mat')
```

Is there a better way to do this? 
I am asking this because via the mentioned way the model file should be in the same directory as the python file (which is not possible always).

Comment: Using a relative path works for me.  Can you show the relative path that you tried to use?

Comment: There shouldn't be anything different about how `loadmat` handles paths - just the usual OS and Python behavior.

Comment: relative path : 'project/assets/model.mat '
sysPath : '/Users/dart/Documents/code/project/assets/model.mat '

loadmat worked with syspath but not with relative path